# Log database queries

Tags: database, logging, trace

I have a fairly complicated groovy script which performs some operations on an Oracle db. Is there a way to log all the queries being performed on the database during a run? I do not have DBA access to the db. It is tedious to trace through the code and figure all the queries being fired. Just was wondering if there was a way to log the actual queries instead.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this plain JDBC or do you use hibernate?

Comment: @cherouvim this is plain JDBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually used this [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/)